# ¿Cómo se puede saber si N es igual a X ó a Y?

Tags: python, operador

Quiero saber si hay algún atajo, cómo por ejemplo los operadores +=, -=, etc. para sumar o restar a otras variables más rápido.

Según mis pocos conocimientos, la única manera sería

```py
N = 4
X = 2
Y = 4
result = N == X or N == Y
```

Pero cuando las variables son más largas, etc., es más complicado entenderlo.

Comment: No sé exactamente a lo que te refieres, pero si el operador walrus ":=" lo consideras como uno de los atajos, te podré decir más. El código con el operador walrus quedaría así: 'result=(N:=4)==(X:=2) or N==(Y:=4)'. Sirve para definir variables. Se puede utilizar casi siempre, incluso en prints

Comment: Podés usar el operador in: n in (x, y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Operador walrus

**Para definir variables**. En caso de que el valor asignado a la variable sea una operación o una expresión, la asignación debe estar **entre paréntesis**

```
print(x:=0)
print(x)
```

## Operador terniario

Para meter un if-else. Si quieres meter un elif, debes utilizar "... else output if condition ...). **Siempre debes definir else**, si no SyntaxError.

```
print(0 if 1==0 else 2 if 1==2 else 1) # Devuelve 1
```

Otra manera no recomendada (no se usa) que utiliza la siguiente sintaxis -> (output, output1)[bool/condition]
Devuelve output si condition==False y output1 si condition==True

```
print((0, 1)[True]) # Devuelve 1
```

## Operador de pertenencia

Para verificar si algo esta en un sitio.

```
print(0 in [0,1]) # Devuelve True
```

## Otros atajos

## Comprensión de listas

Para acortar en una línea bucles for que almacena los valores de una lista que cumple una condición. Sintaxis: [output   for loops   conditions]

```
print([x for x in [0,1,2,3,4,5] if x%2==0]) # Devuelve [0,2,4]
```

## Funciones map, filter, lambda

```
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(list(map(lambda x: x**2, numeros))) # Devuelve [1, 4, 9, 16, 25] -> recorre los valores de numeros y crea una lista con esos números^2

numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, numeros))) # Devuelve los números que sean pares de la lista números

mul=lambda x, y: x*y
print(mul(4, 5)) # Devuelve 4*5 = 20
```

Enlaces de interés:
· [Enlace 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/powerful-one-liner-python-codes/)
· [Enlace 2](https://blog.finxter.com/python-one-liners/)
· [Enalce 3](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-one-liners/)